# Motion of rocket in flat space

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, acceleration

Assume a rocket in hypothetical flat space which is at rest with thrusters off.

The role of thrusters is to help the rocket accelerate.
If the rocket has to move with uniform velocity it will first switch on its thrusters to gain some speed and then switch it off for the rest of the journey. Is this statement correct? If the rocket has to take a U turn in between will it have to switch on thrusters when turning and then again switch them off after taking the turn?

If it has to accelerate for the whole time will the thrusters be switched on for the whole time assuming it also has to take a U turn?

Comment: The short answer is Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the rocket has to move with uniform velocity it will first switch on its thrusters to gain some speed and then switch it off for the rest of the journey. Is this statement correct?

Yes. The velocity it has at the instant it stops accelerating, will be its (constant) velocity after that instant (until the thrusters are turned on again, or any other force acts on the rocket).

> If the rocket has to take a U turn in between will it have to switch on thrusters when turning and then again switch them off after taking the turn?

Yes. Whenever the thrusters are on, the rocket will accelerate. Acceleration means change in velocity (with respect to time), and velocity can change even if speed is constant, if the direction of motion changes. Remember that velocity is a *vector*.

> If it has to accelerate for the whole time will the thrusters be switched on for the whole time assuming it also has to take a U turn?

Once again yes. Thrusters turned on means that a force is acting so the rocket will accelerate. This is consistent with Newton's second law $$\vec F  = \frac{d\vec p}{dt} = m\frac{d\vec v}{dt} = m \vec a$$